# Having a single tips question for all things ES6+

Tags: discussion

**tldr:** Now (a while ago) that the structure of how ECMAScript features are classified into versions has changed, does it make sense to rename and re-purpose the [Tips for Golfing in ECMAScript 6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/tips-for-golfing-in-ecmascript-6) for ES6 and above?

---

At the time of creation of my [ES6 tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37624/tips-for-golfing-in-ecmascript-6) question, ECMAScript versions used to be major versions and contains a lot of features. For the same purpose, a lot of draft specs were written and the scope of a single version was frozen after various draft revisions. This process in tandem with the actual implementation of the feature would take anywhere from 2 to 3 years. The version would contain lots of new features and it would be a major shift in the way JavaScript community works.

Not so long ago, this format changed and the whole major version approach was dropped in favor of an yearly release. This means that new features would be frozen faster and, in turn, would be implemented and shipped in browser faster. Thus, from now on, we have versions like ES2016, ES2017 and likewise. This might lead to very few features of interest being landed in a particular ES version.

Coming to the main point: Keeping all above in mind, does it make sense to repurpose the ES6 tips question for all future ECMAScript versions?

**UPDATE**: Based on the response to this question, I have edited the tips question on the main site to repurpose it for ES6 and above.

Comment: At some point last year I actually edited the question to include ES7, though ES7 was pretty new at the time. The edit was rolled back within a few hours though, and perhaps this is why?

Comment: I edited this question to make it more clear that the **Yes** and **No** actually correspond to the main question (does it make sense to modify the existing ES6 tips question).

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks. I see now that the last line was contradictory to first line and heading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes

We should use the same ES6 tips question for all future ES versions.

Comment: My vote goes to this.

Comment: What would you suggest calling the thread? Tips for ES6+? Tips for ESNext?

Comment: ESNext generally refers to next version which is not yet frozen. How about "ES6 and beyond" ?

Comment: I vote on this. There's no Tips for PHP4, Tips for PHP5 and Tips for PHP7. There's Tips for PHP and that's that.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Why will someone gold in PHP :3

Comment: @Optimizer *golf. Because it is a language I'm familiar with. I'm not perfect at golfing it, but some tricks help to push PHP to the top. (Unless someone answers in a 1-byte-does-everything language)

Comment: @Optimizer Speaking about the devil... : http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102845/14732 (1-byte-solves-everything)